# Android WiFi Direct Network : Can a server(a host) receive the data from two peers (clients) simultaneously?

Tags: android, file, wifi

I am looking for a way that a server in an WiFi Direct network in android can receive the data (i.e. files) from two clients simultaneously.

For instance, the scenario is that tow clients(B and C) will send a file to a server(A) once a connection between one sever and two clients is established.

WiFi Direct Link Condition : there are three android smartphones (A, B, and C)
     A : a server
     B : a client
     C : a Client

```
 A <--> B and A <--> C
```

Here is a question.

If both clients send a files simultaneously, IS a sever able to get both files?
What I found from sample Wi-Fi Direct example from SDK is that a sever is able to get files one by one, not simultaneously.

If there is anyone who can answer or have an experience about the same issue, please let me know. 
Thank you in advance.